# Detect favicon change in userscript

Tags: javascript, events, favicon

I am writing a Tampermonkey userscript, and I need to fire a function on each time the pages favicon changes.

For example:

1. Script on the page changes the pages favicon to another one
2. The userscript detects that, or gets an event of it happening
3. The userscript triggers myFunction()

The favicon on the page is set like this:
`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/dstatic/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" crossorigin="anonymous">`

I tried to use Proxy objects:
`var targetObj = document.querySelectorAll('[rel="shortcut icon"]')[0]; var targetProxy = new Proxy(targetObj, { set: function (target, key, value) { console.log("Favicon changed"); target[key] = value; return true; } });`

I expected:
`console.log("Favicon changed");` fires on favicon change from the pages script.
Result:
This only happens when you call `targetProxy.href`. If you call it with anything other than targetProxy, which is what the page itself does, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Make head as target and observe when rel=icon element will change.

```
const faviconLink = document.querySelector('link[rel="shortcut icon"]');

let observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        if (mutation.attributeName === 'href') {
            console.log('Favicon changed');
            myFunction(); // Call your function
        }
    });
});

const observerConfig = { attributes: true };

observer.observe(faviconLink,observerConfig);
```

I have prepared a working example on [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/vehefezoxu/edit?html,js,console)